# Table Format Report in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I want to design a report in table format. I am using Panel and Line Control for now, but it's time consuming to adjust. Is there a better way to do this?

Example:

---

### | column1  |   column2  |    column3       |

### | aaaaa1   |    sdf     |     sdfsdf       |

### | aaaaa2   |    sdf     |     sdfsdf       |

### | aaaaa3   |    sdf     |     sdfsdf       |

The row background color should be alternating (gray & white).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous I am going to assume you mean using the Report designer you would like to generate a report that looks like the image below.

[image]

That being said you have two different items you have to accomplish the table layout and the alternating Row color.

**For the Table Layout**
Unless I am missing something this is the easy part you only need to use the field controls and border settings on the controls to generate the grids. I have added a screen cap of the standard layout for the report above in the designer

[image]

**For the Alternating Row Color**
This is the challenge because without a little but of work it cant be done. What you have to do is using the visible expression create two sets of duplicate controls one placed directly on top of each other. I used the row number to build my expression that looked like

```
=IIf( $RowNumber % 2 = '0', True, False )
=IIf( $RowNumber % 2 = '0', False, True )
```

That divides each row number by two and if there is a remainder (Bottom equation) shows it and vise versa for the other set of controls.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.. Actually I know this way and build report like this way but, eager to know is there any straight forward way or not.

Comment: This is the only way to do it, I asked the same questions of acumatica when I started using it and this was the only answer they had.